# Select box when function run, displays option values inside but displays elsewhere on the screen too

Tags: php, html, jquery

The issue i have is when i view an select box with parent category option values, they get populated fine but the parent categories not only view in the select box but in the top left corner of the page.

I have a function in my footer using an ajax call to view child categories from the db based on the parent id.

```
    function get_child_options(){
        var parentID = jQuery('#parent').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'parsers/child_categories.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {parentID : parentID},
            success: function(data){
                jQuery('#child').html(data);
            },
            error: function(){alert("Something went wrong with the child options.")},
        });
    }
    jQuery('select[name="parent"]').change(get_child_options);
```

Child_categories.php

```
ob_start();
?>
<option value=""></option>
  <?php while($child = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
    <option value="<?=$child['id'];?>"><?=$child['category'];?></option>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?= ob_get_clean();?>
```

HTML within products page

```
<div class="col-2 ms-3">    
  <label for="child">Child Category:</label>
  <select id="child" name="child" class="form-control"></select>        
</div>
```

All of this works its just i get the parent categories appearing in the top left corner of my page, and i don't know why.
I know when i remove the option value code from the child_categories.php page they disappear, but at the same time the option values don't work.

[[image: image of option box error displaying parent cats]

I have looked at my code hundreds of times to see if i'd put an echo or similar which would be displaying the parent cats, but i can't find anything, and i can't work out why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: At what point are the extraneous entries appearing?  When the page loads or when you change the #parent `select`?  Are you using any other plugin eg [tag:select2] for your "drop down"?  The "undefined index" implies that `Child_categories.php` is getting called without a parentID, which might be the case if it's in the page directly.

Comment: @freedomn-m They are appearing when the page loads. Even when i change the parent select the entries on the page don't change. I have checked and i only a select for the parent. (Edited my original question)

Comment: @freedomn-m The function in the footer is working as it populates the child select.

Comment: After more looking at my code, it turns out within the child_categories.php page, where i added ob_get_clean(); i did <?= not <?php. This has now removed the parent categories from being displayed on the screen. I will work out why ParentID is bringing the error, as the whole flow works, which is odd. Thanks @freedomn-m for your help anyways.